# How to restrict the possible inputs when creating an instance of a class. For e.g. only creating integer instances of a class

Tags: python, oop, arguments, instance

In Python OOP is it possible to restrict the input when creating an object.

For e.g. if I only wanted int objects for a class. So if a string was entered it would return an error.

My initial thought was to write an if statement in the init method that would return an error msg if the conditions were not met.

The only problem with the above is that it seems that returning a statement in an init method is far from ideal.

Any guidance would be much appreciated

Comment: Python doesn't have any automatic type checking. So you need to write it yourself.

Comment: Don't return an error message, raise a `TypeError` exception.

Comment: The return value of the `__init__` method is ignored anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use type suggestions in the method header. This is considered better practices than forcing.

```
def __init__(name: str) -> str:
    return "Hello, " + name
```

If you did need to force you can add isinstance(variable, type) like this.

```
if not isinstance(name, str):
    raise TypeError
```

Answer (score -1):

The basic way you would implement this is to add a check to your `__init__` method that raises an error (usually a `TypeError`) if an incorrect type is passed into the method. You would also want to hint to your readers about the parameters expected type using [function annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html). In practice though, it is generally better to try and *convert* whatever was passed into the `__init__` method into the type that you expect. Python is flexible, and using that flexibility to your advantage is beneficial for you in designing and building your application, as well as for anyone who potentially may want to utilize your code down the line.

An example:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, param: int):
        self.my_param = int(param)
```

In the above example, if you were to wrap your `param` with an exception, the entire application would crash if the exception was left unhandled. If you add the `int()` conversion, it will instead try to convert whatever is passed into an `int`, thereby saving your application from a crash as long as the passed item can be converted. There are cases where you would absolutely want to specify an exact type to be passed, but *flexibility* is usually more important.

Comment: It’s not best practice to handle typing by automatically converting  the variable to an int when this should be done before passing it as a parameter to the __init__. You should never do that, the only time you should is when you know the value can be an int() but if you accepting any value passed in no was to guarantee that it will be of type int.